# Why do return and print statements in for-loop don't work together in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, return-value

Can you please explain why does this function prints `-1` only once, when it has to print it on each loop cycle? However, when I remove line 9 `return -1`, it prints `-1` 4 times, as it should be. How does it work?

```
def find_index(to_search, target):
    enum_tuple = tuple(enumerate(to_search))
    # print(enum_tuple)
    for i, value in enum_tuple:
        if value == target:
            break
        else: 
            print(-1)
            return -1
    return i

my_list = ["Rick", "Amy", "Jack", "Mary"]

index_location = find_index(my_list, "Tom")
```

Comment: You obviously don't know what "return" means, which is basic. So you should read a tutorial. [ask]

Comment: you loop iterates only once, and it either breaks (and then returns `i` which is the next line after the loop) or returns -1. Remove the `return -1` if you want to keep iterating

Comment: What you trying to achieve is not clear. Do you need just debugging of your code or do you want to implement a search function? In which case there is plenty of methods like using `filter()` or `index()` or list comprehension with a predicate, etc. with no need to reinvent what is already there in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you reach line 9 `return -1` you are exiting the function `find_index` so the loop won't continue running.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the next line is executed i.e. `return -1` the command is to return  to the caller and the function is terminated.

If the value that you are searching is found, the statement `return i` is executed and returns the corresponding index.

As you search for `"Tom"` which is not in the list, the `return -1` is hit. Whenever you hit return, the function is terminated and the result is returned to the caller.